# What exactly is the use of event handler accessors/properties?

Tags: c#, interface, eventargs, eventhandler

I have an interface with the line:

```
event EventHandler<MagazineEventArgs> MagazineChangedEvent;
```

When I implement the interface, Visual Studio generates the following template for me:

```
event EventHandler<MagazineEventArgs> IMagazineConfigView.MagazineChangedEvent
{
     add { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
     remove { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

However, I don't understand how exactly I should make use of these properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, you can just use a *field-like event*, e.g. just declare:

```
public event EventHandler<MagazineEventArgs> MagazineChangedEvent;
```

That's *roughly* equivalent to declaring a private delegate field and accessors which subscribe to it and unsubscribe from it:

```
private EventHandler<MagazineEventArgs> magazineChanged;

public event EventHandler<MagazineEventArgs> MagazineChangedEvent
{
    add { magazineChanged += value; }
    remove { magazineChanged -= value; }
}
```

... but the field-like event syntax provides some more thread safety. The exact nature of that thread safety depends on the version of C# you're using. From C# 4 onwards, they're a bit cleaner than they were - see the blog posts of Chris Burrows for more details ([part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx), [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/08/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-ii-semantic-changes-and.aspx), [part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/18/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-iii-breaking-changes.aspx), [afterword](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/30/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-afterward-effective-events.aspx)).

You typically only need to implement the event yourself if you're doing something rather different - for example, chaining event subscription to a *different* underlying event, or to use [`EventHandlerList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx) as a way of efficiently storing sparse subscriptions for a wide range of events.

It's important to understand how events and plain delegate fields differ - it's similar to the difference between properties and fields, although slightly more nuanced as events only have "subscribe and unsubscribe" operations, with no way of the caller *raising* them or determining other subscribers. See [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.